# Delete sharepoint files older than 60 day using Rest api from powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, file

I am working on a powershell script to delete files in a specific folder in SharePoint 2013.

We do not have SharePoint online so the operation must be done with Rest API and from powershell.

Can anyone help?

Comment: share the current script

Answer (score 1):

A caml query will be enough to make the script delete files in a specific folder according to date.

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("site url") 
$web = $site.rootweb 
$list = $web.Lists["library name"]

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$caml='<Where>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2020-02-20</Value>
        </Leq>
    </Where>'

$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output
$query.Folder = $list.RootFolder.SubFolders["folder name"];
write-host $query
$items=$list.GetItems($query) 
write-host $items.Name
$folderItemsTotal = $items.Count;
for($x=$folderItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
        $items[$x].Delete()
}
$web.Dispose() 
$site.Dispose()
```

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c8b6f647-c9f1-475f-b773-f5e0fb754887/sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-delete-files-by-last-modified-date?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below script for your need, this will take **fromDate** and **ToDate** as a parameters which will scan through all documents within that range of dates and delete all files from those date. For your scenario you can give the **FromDate** as 60 days back and **ToDate** as current date.

This script has been developed in PowerShell CSOM object model, so this will fit both in **SharePoint online** and  **SharePoint on-premise**.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
cls



$fileName = "File_Deleting_Report"
#'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
#$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName 

$isLogFileCreated = $False 



#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL

        } 

#DLL location

$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


#File Download location

$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Downloaded Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#File Download location



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 




#Parameters
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/"
$listName="Documents"
$fromDate="2019-12-08"
$toDate="2019-12-12"
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation;
$userName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "YourSPOPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$batchSize =1000

#Parameters ends here.


#Setup the Context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)

  <#
  $web = $ctx.Web
  $ctx.Load($web)
  $ctx.Load($web.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()#>



  #The below code is for root site

$docLibraryColl=$ctx.Web.Lists
$ctx.Load($docLibraryColl)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($oneList in $docLibraryColl)
{

if($oneList.BaseTemplate -eq "101" -and $oneList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $oneList.Hidden -eq $False -and $oneList.IsCatalog -eq $False -and $oneList.IsApplicationList -eq $False) 
{



#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($oneList.Title)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$emptyString = ""
#Define CAML Query to get Files from the list in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery


$startDateVar=$fromDate+"T13:35:58Z"
#$startDate=Get-Date -Date $startDateVar; 
$endDateVar=$toDate+"T13:36:34Z"
#$endDate=Get-Date -Date $endDateVar;



$Query.ViewXml = "@
    <View Scope='Recursive'>
        <Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$startDateVar</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$endDateVar</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>        
    </View>"



$count =0

#Get List Items in Batches
Do
{


    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $ListItems.Count

    #Update Postion of the ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition

    If ($ListItems.Count -eq 0) { Break }

    $fileCount=1;

    #Update List Item
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {                    


            try
            {

              $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

              $Item.File.DeleteObject();
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()              


             Write-Host $Item.File.Name "has been deleted successfully" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen




        }
        catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +$file.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }       



    }
    Write-Host "============================================================="
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host "============================================================="

}While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

}


}
```

For details execution of the above script, please refer the below article :

[SharePoint Online: Delete All Files from document library for the given date – PowerShell CSOM](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/powershell/sharepoint-online-delete-all-files-from-sharepoint-online-site-from-a-given-date/amp/)